# JMeter works with server public IP but doesn't work with domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, jmeter

I want to test the REST API on my server with domain blazingsocket.tk

I set up HTTP Request test using JMeter on my local, below is the configuration:

- Protocol: http
- Servername or IP: blazingsocket.tk
- Port: 80

And this is what I received: Non HTTP response code:java.net.UnknownHostException

I changed the "servername or IP" to my server public IP then it works.

I turned off the firewall on server, nginx web server -> No help.

Web browser and postman are able to resolve the hostname so I don't think DNS had any problem.

Could you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of is that Java is trying to match DNS hostname with the IP address using [IPv6 stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) and fails somewhere somehow.

The solutions are in:

1. Update Java to the most recent version
2. Force Java to use [IPv4 stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4), i.e. run JMeter like:

   ```
   ./jmeter -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true ....
   ```

   if it helps you can make the change permanent by adding the next line to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
   ```

   JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up

References:

- [Networking Properties for Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)